# Generate end points with parameters

Tags: scala, playframework

In Scala Play we have the following way to pass parameters into a URL:

```
ws.url(url).withQueryString("paramKey" -> "paramValue").get()
```

This is fine for urls which use the following pattern:

```
/foo?paramKey=paramValue
```

I have an endpoint defined in my router as follows:

```
GET   /foo/:id/:version
```

I call this endpoint using the WS library. Is there an equivalent method to `withQueryString` that will allow me to generate this URL pattern or do I have to hand-craft my own function?

Answer (score 0):

If this within the same application, then I suppose you can go for: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRouting#Reverse-routing

Otherwise you may just look for some url encoder, which would help you to encode parts of url, but that will not build whole url for you. In the end, the format of the url is completely arbitrary, so there is no way how some library would be able to figure out magically where you want to put your params.

Answer (score 0):

ws.url takes a String, so you want a URI construction library like https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/scala-uri to construct that path for you.  There are also URI template libraries that may be appropriate.